# how to extract a value from database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I want to get a value from a database table using python.
I am sending a query and getting value like this:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password,db=db_name, connect_timeout=10)
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM user_details WHERE email='{}'".format(email)
    for row in cur:
        id = row[0]
```

Is there a way to get the value without using for loop.

Comment: How many values do you expect to get? If just one, you can use `id_=next(cur)[0]`. As a side note, do _not_ call your variables `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find the doc ?

https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.fetchone

> cursor.fetchone()
>
> > Fetch the next row

Also, you definitly DONT want to use string formatting to build your queries ([unless you're ok to have your app wide opened to sql injections of couse)](http://bobby-tables.com/). You want to use prepared queries instead:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM user_details WHERE email=?", [email,])
```

Comment: To get a single value, it should be a = cursor.fetchone(); new_id = a[0];